# Display Password Protected external RSS in wordpress template

Tags: functions, templates, rss

I am using the below code to show external rss feed in my wordpress blog page template:

```
<?php 
  include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
  $rss = fetch_rss('http://feeds.feedburner.com/site-feed');
  $maxitems = 10;
  $items = array_slice($rss->items, 0, $maxitems);
?>
<ul class="arrow">
  <?php if (empty($items)): ?>
    <li>No items</li>
  <?php else:
      foreach ( $items as $item ):
        ?>
        <li>
          <a href='<?php echo $item['link']; ?>' title='<?php echo $item['title']; ?>'>
            <?php echo $item['title']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
        <?php
      endforeach;
    endif;
  ?>
```

The above feed was earlier open but now is password protected.  I already know the user name and password. How to tweak the above code to use user/name password?

Comment: What kind of password protection? Like http authentication?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean fetching an external feed with an *HTTP authentication*.

### Fetching feeds with  HTTP Authentication

Note that `fetch_rss()` uses the *MagPie* library, that's deprecated in WordPress.

Use instead `fetch_feed()` that uses the *SimplePie* library.

It looks though it doesn't support this kind of url:

```
http://user:pass@example.tld/feed/
```

like we can use with `curl` in command-line, e.g.:

```
# curl -i http://user:pass@example.tld/feed/
```

The `fetch_feed()` function calls the `wp_safe_remote_request()` function, to fetch the feed. This is happens in the `WP_SimplePie_File` class, that's an extension of the `SimplePie_File` class.

That's good news, because it means we can use the `http_request_args` filter, to modify the request headers. If we check out the Codex page on the [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API), we see that in the external references, that there's a link to John Blackbourn's short but informative post about [Basic Authentication with the WordPress HTTP API](https://johnblackbourn.com/wordpress-http-api-basicauth). There he gives the following example:

```
$args = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( YOUR_USERNAME . ':' . YOUR_PASSWORD )
    )
);
wp_remote_request( $url, $args );
```

to send the correct authentication header with the request.

### Demo plugin

We can now add a support for the following url type:

```
$rss = fetch_feed( 'http://user:pass@example.tld/feed/' );
```

with the this demo plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Fetch Feeds with http authentication
 * Description: Allows feeds urls like http://user:pass@example.tld/feed/
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199101/26350
 */    
add_action( 'wp_feed_options', function( $feed, $url )
{
    $user = parse_url( $feed->feed_url, PHP_URL_USER );
    $pass = parse_url( $feed->feed_url, PHP_URL_PASS );

    // Nothing to do
    if( ! $user || ! $pass )
        return;

    // Remove the user:pass@ part from the feed url
    $feed->feed_url = str_replace( 
        sprintf( '%s:%s@', $user, $pass ), 
        '', 
        $feed->feed_url
    );

    add_filter( 'http_request_args', function( $r, $url ) use ( $user, $pass )
    {
        // Add the user & pass to the request's header
        if( $user && $pass )
            $r['headers']['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' . base64_encode(  $user . ':' . $pass );
        return $r;
    }, 10, 2 );     

}, 10, 2 );
```

### Update:

This is how the error looks like:

```
WP HTTP Error: A valid URL was not provided.
```

when we run:

```
$rss = fetch_feed( 'http://user:pass@example.tld/feed/' );
```

It comes from the [`WP_Http::request()` method](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0e4606c13e82fa51a3f715b0c0e0ae86a2dd1785/wp-includes/class-http.php#L194):

```
if ( empty( $url ) || empty( $arrURL['scheme'] ) )
    return new WP_Error('http_request_failed', __('A valid URL was not provided.'));
```

Here's how the `wp_safe_remote_request()` function is [defined](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0e4606c13e82fa51a3f715b0c0e0ae86a2dd1785/wp-includes/http.php#L33-L52):

```
function wp_safe_remote_request( $url, $args = array() ) {
        $args['reject_unsafe_urls'] = true;
        $http = _wp_http_get_object();
        return $http->request( $url, $args );
}
```

I was just playing with it and tested:

```
$args['reject_unsafe_urls'] = false;
```

through:

```
add_action( 'wp_feed_options', function( $feed )
{
    $user = parse_url( $feed->feed_url, PHP_URL_USER );
    $pass = parse_url( $feed->feed_url, PHP_URL_PASS );

    if( ! $user || ! $pass )
        return;

    add_filter( 'http_request_args', function( $r, $url ) use ( $user, $pass )
    {
        if( $user && $pass )
            $r['reject_unsafe_urls'] = false;
        return $r;
    }, 10, 2 );     
} );
```

and then this worked:

```
$rss = fetch_feed( 'http://user:pass@example.tld/feed/' );
```

Inside the `WP_Http::request()` method we got this condition:

```
if ( $r['reject_unsafe_urls'] )
    $url = wp_http_validate_url( $url );
```

so it looks like `wp_http_validate_url()` is not validating this url:

```
http://user:pass@example.tld/feed/
```

By setting `reject_unsafe_urls` to false, we skip that check.

There's actually a filter available for this: `http_request_reject_unsafe_urls`, but I wouldn't recommend using:

```
add_filter( `http_request_reject_unsafe_urls`, '__return_false' );
```

I think the demo plugin above, would in general be a better choice, because it still uses the `wp_http_validate_url()` on the auth stripped url.

### Note:

[This part](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0e4606c13e82fa51a3f715b0c0e0ae86a2dd1785/wp-includes/http.php#L460-L461):

```
if ( isset( $parsed_url['user'] ) || isset( $parsed_url['pass'] ) )
    return false;
```

within the `wp_http_validate_url()` function , seems to be the *show-stopper* for `fetch_feed()` for urls with *user:pass*.

Comment: Thank you @kaiser. The `wp_http_validate_url()` seems to be the show-stopper for urls like `http://user:pass@example.tld/feed/`. I don't know if that's unintentional or by design?

Comment: Well, I would assume that `wp_kses_bad_protocol()` is what makes this fail. Aside from that, I personally use the _WP HTTP API_, then load everything in `\DOMDocument` as `1.0` and `UTF-8` and load it with `loadXML`. From there on, it's easy to read the feed using `\DOMXPath::query()` or just `getElementsByTagName()` or the _namespaced_ variants. On top, it allows to use XSD documents to validate the feed and prevent tags that aren't supposed to be in there. That means that it's hard to break on the remote side without knowing it on our side.

Comment: I dug some further and found that it passes `wp_kses_bad_protocol()` but stops within `wp_http_validate_url()`, where there's an [explicit check for user+pass](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0e4606c13e82fa51a3f715b0c0e0ae86a2dd1785/wp-includes/http.php#L460).  That's an interesting approach for dealing with the feeds, you describe. Sometimes when I have to deal with lots of feeds, I've just used `curl` in cron + `simplexml_load_file()` ;-) @kaiser

Comment: The problem with plain `curl` is, that it misses the Certs shipped with WP core. Therefore it might use older Certs (from the OS install on the server) than the rest of the App. This can lead to "funny" results.